# XmlRpcResponse Serialization To c# object

Tags: c#, python, xml, serialization, xml-rpc

I'm new to XmlRpc

I wrote the following :

```
      XmlRpcRequest requestSearch = new XmlRpcRequest("execute_kw");
        requestSearch.AddParams(db, responseLogin.GetInt(), pass, "hr.attendance", "search_read",
                    XmlRpcParameter.AsStruct()
                );

        requestSearch.AddParamStruct(
                     XmlRpcParameter.AsMember("fields", XmlRpcParameter.AsArray("port", "ip"))
                );

     XmlRpcResponse responseSearch = client.Execute(requestSearch);
     string result = responseSearch.GetString();
```

Now I read the following string for example:

```
    [{port: 4370, id: 1, ip: 10.20.1.2}, {port: 4370, id: 2, ip:
    10.20.1.3}, {port: 4370, id: 3, ip: 10.20.1.3}]
```

How do I convert this to object of class

```
 public class Machines
    {
        public int port { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Newtonsoft` for convert string to object. But IP is a string type and should be between quotes.

```
string jsonText = "[{port: 4370, id: 1, ip:'10.20.1.2'}, {port: 4370, id: 2, ip:'10.20.1.3'}, {port: 4370, id: 3, ip: '10.20.1.3'}]";
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Machines>>(jsonText);
```